# Lightning navigation new tab

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm using lightning navigation to redirect to a standard record page. However, the redirection takes place in the same tab. Is there a way to open a new tab?

```
navigateToRecord(event){
        var sRecordId = event.target.dataset.id;
        if(sRecordId!=='' && sRecordId!==undefined ){
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: sRecordId,
                    objectApiName: 'My_Object__c',
                    actionName: 'view'
                },
            });
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: do you mean new tab on browser or new tab on console app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl`. Then use `window.open` to open in a new window.

```
this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
    type: "standard__recordPage",
    attributes: {
        recordId: sRecordId,
        objectApiName: 'My_Object__c',
        actionName: 'view'
    }
}).then(url => {
    window.open(url, "_blank");
});
```

Comment: I actually tried this already. Seems, the redirection takes places before .then() gets called. So it doesn't even enter the .then() context.

Comment: Did you try this code? @sfdcnoob

Comment: @sfdcnoob its this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl] not this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]

Comment: @RahulGawale I am using the above to show standard new creation page however it open a Modal. I want to show it on new salesforce tab in same window tab instead of new window tab and Modal. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @sfdcLearner new form will always open in modal instead of new page. This is standard behaviour