# How to open LWC in new tab on click of quick action?

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

How to open LWC in new tab on click of quick action?

If I click on a quick action, then that should LWC redirect to a new tab like in the attached image:

[image]

Comment: welcome to SFSE,  you can not make `quickaction` as separate tab you can achieve button action.

Answer (score 1):

I can't perfectly understand what you are saying . But from my understanding to open a new tab we can use `window.open()` in Javascript.
We can specify the URL there . Also to open a Salesforce url we can use `NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl`

Have a look at these links:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

[Lightning navigation new tab](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313571/lightning-navigation-new-tab)