# How to open a LWC component in a different page when a lightning quick action is clicked

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have created a patent componet to open a child component and created a lightning-quick action on the Account page

```
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMaxin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class ProdcutsPurchasedParent extends NavigationMaxin(LightningElement) {
    handleNavigate() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__component",
            attributes: {
                componentName: "c:ProductsPurchased"
            },
            state: {
                c__propertyValue: '500'
            }
        });
    }
    connectedCallback(){
        this.handleNavigate();
    }
}
```

but above code is not working as expected .LWC component is not opening in a new page .

Comment: Does this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313571/lightning-navigation-new-tab) help you?

Comment: Thanks, @HemantJain
I have tried the code but it's not working the child LWC component is opening like a pop-up

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the updated code?